A difficult to understand but compact solution without manual counting to a combinatorics question
I was doing a question on matrices which went thus:
Let $A$ be the $2 \times 2$ matrices given by $A = [a_{ij}]$, where $a_{ij} \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ such that $a_{11} + a_{12} + a_{21} + a_{22} = 4$. The number of matrices A such that A is invertible are?
My approach:
I first calculate the total number of matrices (35) using multinomial theorem and then proceeded to manually count the matrices that were non-invertible, i.e. their determinant was zero (17). Hence, the answer: 35 - 17 = 18
However, the process seemed to be a bit lengthy, and I tried to find a easier solution which did not involve manual counting. After no success, I looked back in the solutions to find this:
\begin{equation}
\text{Exactly one zero} = 4 \times (4-3+2)C2 = 12
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{Exactly two zeroes} = 2 \times (4-2+1)C1 = 6
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{Total number of invertible matrices A} = 12 + 6 = 18
\end{equation}
Now, this seems to give me inkling of multinomial being applied but I have no idea how would I translate all the given conditions into a neat little expression given at the back.
Any thought on how to arrive at the solution given in the back? (Or perhaps some other solution not involving manual counting)?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Use descriptive titles. "A mysterious but much easier solution to a lengthy problem" says nothing about the subject of the question.

All the elements can't be nonzero because they sum to $4$ and are are non-negative and the case all equal to $1$ is ruled out (not invertible).
Further, $3$ or more zero elements makes the matrix non-invertible.
So we're left with the cases exactly $1$ or $2$.
Exactly $1$ zero element
In this case, the matrix is automatically invertible, since the determinant is a product of two non-zero numbers. So we just need to count how many ways three numbers in the range $\{1,2,3,4\}$ can sum to $4$. This is given by stars and bars (notice that the upper bound doesn't have an effect).
The formula $4 \times \binom{3}{2}$ comes from first choosing the element that is zero ($4$ ways) and then doing the stars and bars on the remaining $3$. I don't know why it's written like $\binom{4-3+2}{2}$, maybe the solution had some other method.
Exactly $2$ zero elements
There are two possibilities: either $a_{11}$ and $a_{22}$, or $a_{12}$ and $a_{21}$. Hence the factor of $2$. The binomial coefficient comes from stars and bars like before, now two positive variables summing to $4$.
